# certificate problem in http client in windows server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webclient

Using classes WebClient, HttpClient, WebRequest, etc., it is not possible to send requests to sites like as http://www.irmp3.ir and http://www.resanejavan.com.
This problem can be solved by adding the code ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; It is solved in Windows 10, but it still remains in Windows Server 2012.
I recently tried using curl to request the above sites, it failed on the first try but when I used the "ca-bundle.crt" file, the problem was solved.
I wanted to use curl for http requests in c#, but I found that HttpClient is faster than curl for delayed requests.
Please guide me, I have been facing this problem for more than 2 years. I have read all the posts about this but still no results

Comment: Certificate with HTTPS uses TLS to perform the encryption.  Most server will not work with just HTTP (not secure).  Open certificate with notepad and check the encryption mode.   Old server like 2012 may not been updated to work with new encryption modes. The certificate encryption mode must be compatible with the version of TLS and you may need to use TLS 1.3 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true).  What error are you getting?  TLS is done before the request is sent and you will not get a response if TLS fails.  It you get a response than TLS passed.

Comment: The way to get TLS 1.2 working is *not* to specify it in code. It's to apply all the relevant updates and registry keys, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392, and also to use an up to date version of .NET, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client

Comment: The error that i am getting as follows: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
I will also look at your links and respond you if i successed